# Ajax send JSON like string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

How to send json string via ajax and convert json string to xml?

**Error:** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
$.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/btnSave",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{data: '" + "{'?xml': {'@version': '1.0'},'Card': { 'Main_Client_Information': {'Surname': '','Name': '','Middle_name': '','Full_name': '','Short_name': '','RNN': '','IIN': '','Birthday': '','Doc_Type': {'@code': ''}}}}" + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
```

if send  $.ajax data: '{data: "something"} - work perfect, how to put "**json like string**" instead "something"

**WebForm.aspx.cs**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string btnSave(string data)
    {

        string response = "";

        try
        {

            XmlDocument xmlDocument = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(data);

            xmlDocument.Save(Server.MapPath("output.xml"));

            response = "success";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = "error" + ex.Message;
        }

        return response;

    }
```

Comment: Use `JSON.Stringify`?

Comment: Yeas I have already used it